# unable to add mandrill-webhook

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, rest, mandrill

I have deployed my rest api on azure. and it`s url is like this.

http://{my_deployment_id}.cloudapp.net/myservice.svc/getdata.

I am unable to set this as my webhook. I am getting an error "We can't verify that the URL exists".

Event if I try this with API (https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/webhooks/add.json). I am getting following error.

```
   {
     "status": "error",
     "code": -2,
     "name": "ValidationError",
     "message": "Validation error: {\"url\":\"That is not an existing URL\"}"
   }
```

I am not sure whether it is problem with my Rest API or problem with my mandrill setting.  I am able to hit my rest api using postman.

Answer (score 3):

If you click the help link it offers, it tells you that it first does a HEAD request to the endpoint, expecting a 200, and then does a POST if that fails, expecting a 200. If it doesn't get a 200 in one of those cases, then it will not add the endpoint.

A silly arbitrary requirement from Mandrill. It's a catch-22 in fact. You need to add the endpoint to get the key, so that you can fully configure your endpoint.